# Python requests extremely slow in a specific machine

Tags: python, python-requests

I found that the requests module works extremely slow in my laptop, something like this will take more than 3 minutes to complete.

```
    import requests
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
    r.text
```

I can access that page using browser with no delay, I can run this in google colaboratory within a second, I can run it on another computer using the same network within a second, so there must be something wrong with my laptop.

But how can I know what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Likely this something entirey to do with _your_ environment, so may be impossible to diagnose remotely. Have you tried tracing network communication with something like Telerik Fiddler and comparing Python vs Browser?

Comment: To be honest, I have never heard Telerik Fiddler. I try it, it could catch it when I use a browser to open a page, but nothing is shown when I use python requests.

Comment: You might have to make Requests use Fiddler as a proxy. Or try Wireshark or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

thé time To reach the server may be different because of different dns network resolution. implied by different network setting on this computer. you can watch the path To reach github using traceroute or tracepath  api.github.com